# What is ``npm install ../my-another-package'' in Rust's Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In my Cargo.toml, I defined `[dependencies]` like:

```
[dependencies]
my-another-package = "0.0.1"
```

But I don't want to put `my_another_package` on GitHub because it is proprietary. I want to install it from my local disk. Using NPM, I would do something like `npm install ../my-another-package`.

Comment: can't you simply use `git = "/path/to/package"` like you'd use a github package that isn't on crates.io? I thought whatever's behind the git link will be processed by git and not cargo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want what Cargo calls a ["path dependency"](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html#path-dependencies):

```
[dependencies.my-another-package]
path = "path/to/my-another-package"
```

Comment: And the version can be put in if desired with `version = "0.0.1"`.